# ¿Por qué las cosas fáciles se hacen "con la gorra"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, modismos

Es común, al menos en España, decir que algo se ha hecho "con la gorra" cuando se hace sin mayor esfuerzo.

> Ese chico es muy listo. Saca la mayor nota en todos los exámenes con
>   la gorra.

De hecho, incluso la RAE lo menciona:

> **[con la gorra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JMIxQbW)**
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. Fácilmente, sin esfuerzo.

Me pregunto: ¿por qué esta expresión? ¿Se referirá a la época en la que todo el mundo llevaba gorra o sombrero, en la cual todo pequeño esfuerzo conllevaba quitárselo para ponerse "manos a la obra"?

Comment: Aquí (Argentina) no se usa, ni yo la conocía. Sí conocía "de gorra" como "gratis, a costa ajena" (pero tampoco se usa mucho).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo, es posible que, la frase se origina de trabajo manual, en el cual trabajadores manuales que tengan que quitar su gorra solamente de mano de obra suficientemente intensa como para sudar.

Answer (score 3):

En el programa *Hablando Plata* de [RNE-Radio5 se explicó](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/audios/hablando-en-plata/hablando-plata-comer-gorra-03-10-11/1213276/).

Corroborado por este articulo de [academia andaluza](http://www.academia.andaluza.net/en/practicar/la-frase-de-la-semana/comer-de-gorra/):

> *Origen*
>
> En los siglos XVI – XVII en la ciudad de Salamanca (España), los
>   estudiantes tienen muy poco dinero para vivir. En este tiempo los
>   estudiantes llevan gorra, y buscan sistemas y soluciones para poder
>   comer gratis. La gorra y esa práctica producen esta expresión.
>
> *Significado*
>
> Usamos la frase “Comer de gorra” o “Hacer algo de gorra” cuando
>   comemos o hacemos alguna acción para la que es necesario tener dinero…
>   gratis, es decir, no pagamos dinero. Expresiones similares son “Comer
>   / hacer algo por la cara” o “Comer / hacer algo de balde”.)

O en este otro articulo del diario [libertad digital](http://www.libertaddigital.com/opinion/amando-de-miguel/hechos-y-dichos-38354/)

> Del comer de gorra, en la entrada del diccionario, "de gorra" en su
>   forma adverbial se define como "a costa ajena", y de allí que sea la
>   RAE lo defina como fácilmente.

O como se oye en el audio, "ir/va de gorra" cuando lo consigue todo gratis, fácilmente.

Comment: Hacer algo **de gorra** significa hacerlo de forma gratuita. Hacer algo **con la gorra** significa hacerlo con gran facilidad y/o soltura. Son expresiones distintas, y aunque es posible que tengan el mismo origen, no creo que las referencias alcancen a explicar el segundo uso.

Answer (score 1):

La realidad es que no lo sé. Pero me imagino que podría ser porque indica que la persona pudo hacerlo sin tener por qué quitarse la gorra. Cuando uno está afuera trabajando y sudando, de vez en cuando tiene que quitarse la gorra para quitar el sudor de la frente.

Answer (score 1):

Respecto a "con la gorra" es una equivalencia a "sin despeinarse", es decir que exige poco esfuerzo y que puede realizarse hasta - con la gorra - puesta; y a "de gorra" se explica cuándo alguien acude a un evento sin invitación siendo ir de gorra un gesto de informalidad a diferencia del resto y por tanto obteniendo un beneficio inmerecido o gratuito.